# how to get specific information from list in flutter

Tags: list, flutter, listview, listviewitem

I'm developing a flutter application composed by three screens , the first one is a list view widget were I can fetch the data from a list variable , something like this:

here is the list view:

```
 child: ListView.builder(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: 10.0,
                    ),
                    itemCount: data.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      final 2data =data[index];

                      return GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          Navigator.push(context, 
                              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                            return dataSecondScreen(data: 2data,);
                          }));
                        },
```

here is the list where I define the data

```
final List<Data> data = [ //Data is a class
  Data(
    1, //id
    "Eli", //name
    18, //years old

    ),

 Data(
    2, //id
    "Axel", //name
    23, //years old

)]
```

When I press a list view item, it redirects me to another screens were it show me all the information of the list (depending the index that I press before, I mean, If I press a item with index 1 , in the second screen I can see the información of the item with index 1)

Here is my problem, in the second screen, where I have all the information of the item with index 1 ,I have a clickable image, and I want something like this:
if I click that image I want to change the state (or move to another screen) with different index  , for example, If I'm in the screen with all the information of the index 1, I want to be able to click the image and change the information of the index 1 screen for the index 2 (or 3,4 ,5...). so, How I can be able to select and show the information that I want from a list?

UPDATE:

in this section i'm tried to apply PageView in order to move between pages, however, when I scroll left only appear the same first item, the second one is never showing it

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Constant.main ? Init( ) : Stadis());
  }
```

here is the PageView

```
 Widget Init(){
    int activeIndex = 0;
    final screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    int selectedIcon = 0;
    return PageView.builder(
      itemCount: data.length,
        physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
      controller: _controller,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {

          return Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Column(...
```

Comment: Please elaborate on your question

Comment: Sir I want to know how I cans elect a position of a list depending for  example the id (that I already defined )and show it in the screen

Answer (score 1):

you should use State management packages to manage your state with better performance and easier development.
here are some of the state management packages to see:

1-https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc

2-https://pub.dev/packages/provider

the first one is bigger and suitable for big scale projects and the second is for a medium and small projects.
Although that's fine to use each of them for your projects.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use the Widget PageView for this purpose: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageView-class.html

You can use the PageView.builder to iterate through the list of items.

For example:

Suppose this is what your data looks like:

```
class Profile {
  final int id;
  final String name;
  final int age;

  Profile(this.id, this.name, this.age);
}
```

And a list of item:

```
List<Profile> data = [Profile(1, "Eli", 18), Profile(2, "Axel", 23)];
```

Then in the build method of your page:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: PageView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Text(data[index].name);
        },
        itemCount: data.length,
      ),
    );
  }
```

If you scroll left, it will go to data[2], if you scroll right, it will go to data[1].

Comment: Pageview looks to be the solution.. however I have the same problem, I'm trying to jump to to Data[2] from to Data[1]and I cant get it..  do you know how I can jump from Data[1] to Data[2]?  I have the controller.. I defined the currentPage.. and anything works..

Comment: I am not sure I understand fully. But I have edited the answer above with a simple example. It will display the data[index].name depending on which item the pageview is on. You can return a custom widget instead of Text(...) to display all data elements.

Comment: Thanks for the code, however, it doesn't appear to be working for me, I update my ask section showing how I applied the PageView mmm I think my problem is with my list view, when I move from the list view to the new screen I take one item in the list (the one that I press), so in the second screen I have only one item , this is why, even if I have the PageView I can only move just with the first item

Comment: Then yes, you will need to pass the single data element and the full-list to the constructor of the widget that builds the PageView. This is probably not a clean way to do it however.

Comment: mm I´m going to try that just for check it. From the list view class, now I'm sending the single data and the full list as you can see here: `return dataSecondScreen(data: 2data, list:list);`, so now the constructor of the PageView widget may have the full list, ins't it? however, looking to my code ,how I can I pass that list to the page view?